# Can I learn LDAP online?

Tags: ldap, openldap

Does anyone know of any good online material to learn about LDAP?  I'm not looking for how to implement it.  I'd like to learn about the protocol itself in depth rather than just a conceptual understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the protocol is documented in a series of RFCs starting with **[RFC 4510](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4510)**. Quote:

> The technical specification detailing version 3 of the Lightweight
> Directory Access Protocol (LDAP), an Internet Protocol, consists of
> this document and the following documents:

> - LDAP: The Protocol [[RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511)]
> - LDAP: Directory Information Models [[RFC4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512)]
> - LDAP: Authentication Methods and Security Mechanisms [[RFC4513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4513)]
> - LDAP: String Representation of Distinguished Names [RFC4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514)]
> - LDAP: String Representation of Search Filters [[RFC4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515)]
> - LDAP: Uniform Resource Locator [[RFC4516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4516)]
> - LDAP: Syntaxes and Matching Rules [[RFC4517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517)]
> - LDAP: Internationalized String Preparation [[RFC4518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4518)]
> - LDAP: Schema for User Applications [[RFC4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519)]

In addition to those, RFC 4510 also has a list of *old* RFCs that these replace, and a list of *extensions* documented in other RFCs, so please start there and do not consider the above snippet complete.